# How do i prevent a function being run more than once on a jquery .live event

Tags: jquery

Ok i am reediting my post as i  think it could be more clear.

I have a ASP.net page with a gridview etc on.

On the result rows of the gridview is an image that when clicked opens up a modal popup window (basically a hidden div that is shown on click).

That modal, as it appears is populated dynamically by some ajax/json with a 2 column table, column 1 just text rows, column 2 combination of empty dropdown lists and check boxes.(these are all added to the DOM AFTER the main page load).

I am trying to populate the checklists with their available  via ajax/json when they are clicked by the user, and i only want this to happen on the first click only and no matter how many times the user clicks on that dropdown there after (even after going out of focus and back) i don't want to see more repeats of the same  appear.

Here is the code that currently works when the dropdown is clicked, that is the dropdown is populated. Te problem is if i loose focus and then re-click the dropdown, it gets repopulated with a duplicate list of :

```
<code> 
    $('#FSSiteName').live('focus', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        getFSSites();
        //i thought the below line would stop it happening again when i click on the dropdown
    $this.unbind('focus');
});

 function getFSSites() {
            var ddSites = $("#FSSiteName");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Circuits_OrderManagementTracker.aspx/getTheSitesList",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
                    var xml = $(xmlDoc);
                    var FSSitesReturned = xml.find("Table");

                    $.each(FSSitesReturned, function (index, FSSitesReturned) {
                        dbname = $(this).find("SiteNames").text()
                        ddSites.append('<option>' + dbname + '</option>');
                    });
                },
                failure: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg);
                }
            });
        }
</code>
```

I have changed to the code below on suggestions by your good selves, but when i do the below my dropdown list no longer gets populated and i also tried .one() which ad the same effect.

```
<code>
         $('#FSSiteName').on('click', function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            //run your alert here if it´s necessary
            //alert('Focused for the first time :)');
            getFSSites();
            //unbind the event to prevent it from being triggered again
            $this.off('click');
         });
</code>
```

Hope this is a bit clearer to anyone wishing to help.

Comment: did you try `.one()`: http://api.jquery.com/one/ ?

Comment: Are you building a framework for reuse? If not I'd recommend just leveraging one that does all of this for you like [Telerik's Kendo](http://www.kendoui.com)

Comment: .one() will only trigger it once per context element, not per delegate target.

Comment: Id's must be unique. Also, to unbind a live event, use `.die`

Comment: i tried .one and the popultation of the dropdown did not work. i tried .die and the result was the same as the start the dropdown populates nicely, but then susiquent clicks added additional repeat populations of the same options

Answer (score 1):

The opposite of `live()` is `die()` but [both are deprecated](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#die-removed), you should use `on()` and `off` instead.

Comment: actually, `.one()` is better suited in this scenario.

Comment: @Flater using any of .on() or .one() worked for me as these seemed to prevent getFSSites() from running. I can only assume at this stage that it is because .Live() is picking up on the newly added #FSSiteName to the DOM and the others simply dont see them?

Comment: Didn't say it doesn't work :) But `.one()` has been specifically created to be run only once, without having to unbind the handler yourself.

Comment: @Flater thank you Flater, i still found your comment useful and learned something from it.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple using on and off.

on() -> add an evend handler
off() -> remove an event handler

```
$("#item li").on('click', function () {
    $(this).text('ITEM CLICKED')
    alert('CLICKED');

    //remove the event
    $(this).off("click")
});
```

see this example: http://jsfiddle.net/jMxxa/

***Jquery documentation for on and off:***

**on:** http://api.jquery.com/on/
**off:** http://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: thanks Kesymaru but if i use the .on and .off the list no longer gets populate dynamically? #FSSiteName is not present on page load its only added dynamically when the popup is loaded and the table is added dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Varnie's comment to use .one instead of .live().

```
$('#FSSiteName').one('focus', function () {
        getFSSites();
 });
```

Live() is intended for use with elements that are dynamically added to the DOM; elements that do not exist when the page is first loaded in the browser. Since your element has an id selector, not a class selector, I'm assuming you don't need to use .live()/.on() at all.

Comment: Hi Steve, i am using live() because the elements are indeed added dynamically when the popup modal appears and therefore the empty dropdown lists. the problem is that .on() does not work only live seems to fill the dropdown list. I tried .one() and that seems to stop the lists from being dynamically filled. im just a bit to new to figure it out and you advise is appreciated

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post your full code on a site like jsfiddle or plnkr?

Comment: Hi Steve I dont think so in its entirety, however i will edit my OP to be more clear and show more code...

Comment: Thanks for editing the OP. You may get more insight by also describing any errors thrown in Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools. I'm not seeing anything in your expanded code sample that would stop once() or on()/off() from working.

Answer (score 0):

Hi All thank you for your help, this is really one of the best sites i have got to know as a learner.

i have put in a solution myself which seems to do the trick, however being so new to coding, i would appreciate feedback if i have done something that is not ideal and there is a better simpler solution.

i re edited my OP to be more clear see above and that still stands, however i changed some of my code to merely check if the dropdown was empty of  and it works ok see:

```
<code>
         $('#FSSiteName').live('click', function () {
             var $this = $(this);
             //Check if the dropdown has any options and if no add some
             if ($this.find('option').length <= 1) {
                 getFSSites();
             }
             else {
                //Do Nothing!!
             }            
         });

</code>
```